# Enable green squiggles for warnings in VS Code for C++

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hey I have intalled VS Code in my Linux machine. I am using it for my C++ project. I've installed the recommended C++ Intellisense plugin but VS code isn't showing green squiggles for any warning e.g decleration of an unused variable. Any solution?

Comment: any luck on this?  a star appeared allowing me to disable, then no way to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by editing the Workspace Settings.  Click the Settings gear icon then open/unfold the C/C++ section of the Workspace Settings JSON.
Edit it to say "Enabled".

```
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
```